# WAMP server not starting Windows 7

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

I had installed `wamp` server successfully but after starting all services it's not turning into green. I don't know exact problem also there is no port blocking problem.

Default Apache port 80 is not using by any other program.

I am trying to find out the error but not getting any.
All the error log files are empty.

I also checked mysql port and don't have any issue.

Comment: let me guess, you are running Skype ?

Comment: no i never installed

Comment: did u install `VC11` ?

Comment: what VC11? and did't installed

Comment: what happened when you requested localhost in browser? what are services you start? windows services or what?

Comment: When you download `wamp`, you can see a link to download it, it is required [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). @MangeshShelke

Comment: @Viral yes i downloaded Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have WAMP instaled before on this current windows machine?
Did you select the explorer.exe when promted?

I had same problem after i tried to instal wamp on same location where the last one was.

You need to uninstall the current wamp, delete the folder, clean you system registries and junk files, use ccleaner for this and then instal wamp again.

Comment: yes i had installed wamp a long time back but i uninstalled it

Answer (score 0):

I know you are professional but I will give this suggestion considering that you still beginner :

remove this one completely and reboot your machine then create new folder ,if you have tow or three partition , create it in D and name it for example wamp.

when you start installation make sure that you select correct path to your folder wamp and when you write a server name , just write localhost without .com then write the user user@localhost and make password.

after that type at  browser localhost and see what what happened.